# Auto-incrementing in database vs ORM tool

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

Auto-incrementing primary key vs auto-incrementing in ORM tool.

1. I am using Hibernate as my ORM tool and using below code to auto-increment my primary key:-

```java
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

2. My connected Db Postgress also provides auto-incrementing feature:-

```sql
geo_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('geo_id_seq') PRIMARY KEY
```

Is there any performance difference between these two?

Comment: There is performance diffrence between [identity and sequence](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-serial-column-hibernate-identity/) when using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't.  The hibernate statement will fetch the values from an identity column in your table, which is backed-up by a sequence in Postgres. The key to understand is that the value is **not** generated by the ORM but by the database in both cases.

You can read a bit more [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators) and [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/).